# selected word in javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible at all to get the position indexes after and before the selected word to store at new array?

Comment: You really need to clarify this question. It's completely unclear what you mean by "selected word".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. By using the document.selection object:

http://www.webreference.com/js/column12/selectionobject.html